# Port forward to my web server's machine catches visitors IPs as my public IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, nat

I have local machine runs as web server, its IP is 192.168.1.xxx. On my ADSL router, I have created port forward "NAT" to this machine, **it works fine**, but the logged IPs of visitors from the Internet to my web server always is assigned to my public IP not their IPs.

I have tried to make DMZ to the local server IP and changing NAT settings from ADSL settings from NAPT to Full Cone NAT.

#### Update 1:

The web server is Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 and I use the following [php](/questions/tagged/php) code to track user's IP:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        //Perform login tracking
        $log = new Loginlog();
        $log->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $log->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $log->est_ip = $ip;
        $log->save();
        $nowDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));        
        $deletedRows = \App\Loginlog::where('created_at','<', $nowDate->subDays(config('fox.clearBeforeDays')))->delete();
        // dd(\Auth::user()->id,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    }
```

#### Update 2:

After removing all NAT roles shown in the second screen shot and just keeping DMZ shown in the third screen shot, the above PHP code succeeded in catching the client's IP correctly!

The question: what's wrong in NAT that prevented the server or at least the script running on it from catching the client's IP while DMZ only allowed this. The problem with using DMZ, that it makes my server's machine ports opened to all Internet Inbound traffic!

The following are screen shots of my Router's config related:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is impossible. In your (unspecified) web server there must be a mistake and you're using the wrong message field. You need to give more information about what you are doing in the web server.

Comment: @harrymc Please checkout updates added to the question.

Comment: It's a weird router that you have there.

Comment: @harrymc It is Huawei HG531 V1

Comment: If I understand rightly, your router apparently has a mode where it modifies the packets and substitutes the remote IP. Now that you have found it, what remains to be done?

Comment: @harrymc DMZ reduce the security by loss the router's firewall protection. i.e all ports on the local machine are available from WAN. Hence, I'm looking for any possible way to keep NAT but keeping catching IPs or like you described, stopping the router's packets modification.

Comment: You should avoid DMZ, but rather use port forwarding. See [link](https://portforward.com/huawei/hg531-v1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid DMZ, as it is too risky, giving everyone on the Internet
a direct access to all your ports.

Yous should rather use port forwarding.

See the Port Forwarding article :
[Simple Instructions to Help Setup a Port Forward on the Huawei HG531 V1 Router](https://portforward.com/huawei/hg531-v1/)

Comment: You had mentioned to valuable point in your comments: "*your router apparently has a mode where it modifies the packets and substitutes the remote IP*", I replaced the router regarded above with another one, ZTE ZXHN H108N V2.5 and it works fine!, so the Huawei router has an issue or missing or unknown configuration aspect in its firmware that generates this issue. I'd like to confirm again, I have no problem with forwarding traffic to my local machine, it is only the client's IP issue.

Comment: You would need to look at the available parameters. I have downloaded the manual for your router, but it is really a joke and has almost no information at all. Not sure you will find anything, if it's a built-in mode.

Comment:  yes sure it is, generally, a bunch of words to let them say "Hay we have a manual"